# Vue component prop value is undefined when accessing from template

Tags: vue.js

I created 2 Vue components:

```
Vue.component('vimeo', {
    template: '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + this.videoId + '" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    props: ['videoId']
});

Vue.component('videos', {
    template: '<div id="videos">' + 
                '<div v-for="videoId in videoIds">' +
                    '<vimeo :video-id="videoId"></vimeo>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>',
    computed: {
        videoIds: function() {
            return store.state.videoIds;
        }
    }
});
```

However, the this.videoId is always undefined in the 'vimeo' component template. If I change the template to:

```
<h1>{{ videoId }}</h1>
```

the prop value can be displayed properly.

I have searched the internet for solutions to this, but unfortunately, I have not got any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is basically trying to use `this.videoId` at the time of the *template definition*, before any components have been initialized.

Instead what you'll have to do is [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) the `videoId` value so that it is translated at *render time*. I would do this with a computed property since you need to concatenate the vimeo URL prefix.

Something like:

```
computed: {
  videoUrl() { return 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + this.videoId; }
},
template: '<iframe :src="videoUrl" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

Note the colon in `:src` for the dynamic binding. [See the docs for more info on this.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)